# What happens to CKRecords of a CloudkitZone when zone is deleted

Tags: cloudkit, zone, ckrecord

I can not find this in documentation but what would happen if a CloudKit zone is deleted? what happens to the CKRecords associated with that zone? are they deleted also? Is there e a constrain that you can delete a zone when has not records in it?

Answer (score 1):

When a zone is deleted, the records in that zone are deleted. There is no constraint about deleting a zone - you can delete a zone with no records, or with many.

Comment: Any documentation reference?

Comment: I'm just speaking from my experience, if you're not finding it in the docs I doubt I will either.

Comment: Direct experience is good, well we might have a documentation here then, thanks.